# soap struct context is not being set in interface file implementation

Tags: c++, gsoap

Upgrading gsoap 2.8.17 to 2.8.108. soapcpp2 generates the interface header file(soap.h) and corresponding implementations (soapC.cpp). This has some functions to instantiate soap objects having naming pattern `soap_instantiate_*`.

I am observing that the soap context for newly created objects is not getting assigned.

function implementation generated by 2.8.108 :-

```
SOAP_FMAC1 type_abc * SOAP_FMAC2 soap_instantiate_type_abc(struct soap *soap, int n, const char *type, const char *arrayType, size_t *size)
{

  (void)type; (void)arrayType; /* appease -Wall -Werror */
  type_abc *p;
  size_t k = sizeof(type_abc);
  struct soap_clist *cp = soap_link(soap, SOAP_TYPE_type_abc, n, soap_fdelete);
  if (!cp && soap && n != SOAP_NO_LINK_TO_DELETE)
    return NULL;
  if (n < 0)
  { p = SOAP_NEW(soap, type_abc);
    // Should have below line as well ??? 
    // p->soap = soap;
  }
  else
  { p = SOAP_NEW_ARRAY(soap, type_abc, n);
    k *= n;
    // loop through an array assign soap to each objects.
    // p[i].soap = soap;  

  }

  if (size)
    *size = k;
  if (!p)
    soap->error = SOAP_EOM;
  else if (cp)
    cp->ptr = (void*)p;
  return p;
}
```

Function implementation generated by 2.8.17 :-

```
SOAP_FMAC1 type_abc * SOAP_FMAC2 soap_instantiate_type_abc(struct soap *soap, int n, const char *type, const char *arrayType, size_t *size)
{
  (void)type; (void)arrayType; 
  struct soap_clist *cp = soap_link(soap, NULL, SOAP_TYPE_type_abc, n, soap_fdelete);
  if (!cp)
    return NULL;
  if (n < 0)
  { cp->ptr = (void*)SOAP_NEW(type_abc);
    if (size)
      *size = sizeof(type_abc);
    ((type_abc*)cp->ptr)->soap = soap;
  }
  else
  { cp->ptr = (void*)SOAP_NEW_ARRAY(type_abc, n);
    if (size)
      *size = n * sizeof(type_abc);
    if (cp->ptr)
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ((type_abc*)cp->ptr)[i].soap = soap;
  }
  if (!cp->ptr)
    soap->error = SOAP_EOM;
  return (type_abc*)cp->ptr;
}
```

Any idea on how can I preserve this behaviour post upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

The `soap` field must be a `struct soap *soap` type. If it is something different, then the `soap` member will not be assigned in the C++ code.

Example test case:

```
struct ns__X {
  int n;
  struct soap *soap;
};
```

After running `soapcpp2` on this file:

```
SOAP_FMAC1 struct ns__X * SOAP_FMAC2 soap_instantiate_ns__X(struct soap *soap, int n, const char *type, const char *arrayType, size_t *size)
{
...
    if (n < 0)
    {   p = SOAP_NEW(soap, struct ns__X);
        if (p)
            p->soap = soap;
    }
    else
    {   p = SOAP_NEW_ARRAY(soap, struct ns__X, n);
        k *= n;
        if (p)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                p[i].soap = soap;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: In my case public type_abc is inherited from `soap_dom_element` which has default names for member variables. `soap_dom_element` has a member `struct soap *soap`, I think this element will get inherited to type_abc. Any idea what else could go wrong in there?